# Selenium Targeting a hidden element on page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, data-mining

### Using Selenium to interact with authors on Medium.com

I am trying to target a popup element with selenium that appears when text is double-clicked. Once this is detected and clicked it opens a message box to the right. My end goal has been to insert (send_keys) text into this text box and yet it is proving to be quite difficult.

[[the dynamic element]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ASO2.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ASO2.png) # the element on the far right is the button to open the chat box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8guqp.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8guqp.png) # this is the text box

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def interact_with_author(message):
    # variables 
    target_class = "meteredContent"
    body_css = "body"
    header_xpath = "/html/head"
    second_article_css = "#root > div > div.s.n.t > div.ah.ay > div > div.n.p > div > div:nth-child(2)" # the second article on the page
    first_par = "#\39 993"
    second_par = "#\35 f50"
    first_par_css = "#root > div > div.s > article > div > section > div > div > p"
    first_par_class = "ht hu dj hv b ei hw hx hy el hz ia ib ic id ie if ig ih ii ij ik il im in io db eg"
    wait_time = 5 # seconds to wait when sleep is called with the wait_time variable
    
    #code
    text_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(47) > div > div > div > div > div')
    action = ActionChains(driver) 
    listing=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,"a")))
    articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    an_article = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(second_article_css)
    an_article.click()
    
    time.sleep(wait_time) # todo change to sleep four seconds after the article is fully loaded
    
    listing=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,"p")))

    try:  
        paragraphs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
        
        driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='250%'")

        try:
            first_par = '' 
            for i in range(1,len(paragraphs)):
                first_par_commentable = None
                try:
                    first_par_commentable = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/article/div/section/div/div/p[{i}]")
                    driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='200%'")
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    ic(e)
                if first_par_commentable != None:
                    break
        except Exception as f:
            ic(f)
        try:
            first_par_commentable.click()
            action.double_click(first_par_commentable).perform()
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
        except Exception as e:
            ic(e)
    except Exception as e:
        ic(e)
```

'''

If anyone knows how to access this element quickly and in a scaleable way it would be appreciated.

'''

Comment: Could you mention step by step to reach to that text box. Also please be clearer about left and right.

Comment: the targeted element is the right-most icon in the first photo that looks like a chat bubble.

Comment: steps: double click on any text in the article, select comment icon, type your comment into the field, then hit submit